# What is the name of this pendulum?

Tags: waves, orbital-motion, terminology, oscillators, harmonics

[image: The pendulum]

What is the name of a pendulum with two parallel string hung vertical to a rod, and giving the rod an initial force would make it swing left and right, doing simple harmonic motion?

What is the mechanism and formulae of it, or its significance/ related works?

Comment: I name all pendulums “Bob”. For obvious reasons